# How to refetch query again with 8base

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm using this method to fetch list from 8base database, but I want to refetch query again to fetch latest data but not able to recall it again.

```
client.query({
  query: QUERY_HERE
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res, 'test')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a little bit more about the `client` module you are initializing as well as explain what you mean be refetch?

Are you saying refetch in terms of simply re-running the request? Or are you talking about refetching a cached response from the client?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to put the client call in a function that you can call again/re-use. For example:

```
function getData() {
  client.query({
    query: QUERY_HERE
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res, 'test')
  })
}

// Call function
getData()

// Call function on button click
document.getElementById("myButton").on("click", getData)
```